# angular cli build does not include css component

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Reading the angular-cli documentation and  some discussion on stack overflow I had understand that when a project is done with generated components, the inline styles will be all included in the build by default, but when I build my project it seems that none of the inline styles were included.

For example this component:

### Component

```
import { MenubarService } from '../../services/menubar-service/menubar.service'
 
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers:[LoginService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(.......
```

the login.component.css file is not present in the final project. I have noticed it for two reason:
First clearly the style of my app is different from the one that I have when I use 'ng serve' command and second because with the browser inspector element I don't find trace of my css.

That's my angular-cli's configuration file

```
{
  "project": {
  "version": "1.0.0-beta.18",
  "name": "genioimprese"
},
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "images",
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "paper.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    } 
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

except for some styles and assets it's clearly the default file of a new angular-cli projects. I think there's something wrong in my configuration file but the only documentation that I found is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), and I didn't find anything that helps me.

## CSS

```
a{
    color: #0c699e;
}
a:hover,a:active,a:focus{
    color: #218fce;
}

.login{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 7%;
}
.login > .logo{
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
}
.input[type='text']{
    background-color: grey;
    color: #218fce;
    border: none; 
    border-radius: 0;
}  
h4{
    color: #218fce;
}
.form-group{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
form{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.checkbox-inline{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit: nevermind, it's not...
What is this doing in your config: `"inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },`? I have not seen this before. Could it be related?

Comment: Actually, in the prod bundle, there will not be a login.component.css. angular-cli (webpack) will bundle your css differently than in the normal `ng serve` build. Could it be a caching issue which affects that styles in your prod build do get shown differently than in the dev build? Can you show some css maybe?

Comment: @Riscie no i have not edit that piece of code, but i have the same suspect about thei style value. But the problem is that there is none of the style tag in the prod bundle, i can let you see the css code but it's a real simple piece of code.

Comment: And doing `ng build --prod` is where your styles do not get displayed, right? When opening that production build in your browser, did you open the console or network tab in the dev-tools to see wether there are some issues?

Comment: yes is the prod build that i check,no issues in the console, i think that something missing, do you want to see the dist folder?

Comment: @Riscie i have cleaned the cache, now i notice the the inline styles are not presents even in the serve mode.

Comment: This is weird... Maybe still try to remove the ./ at the beginning of the styleurls path like so `  styleUrls: ['login.component.css'],` and also update to angular-cli beta 19. But... I mean I have the same config here and it works so, nut sure...

Comment: I have resolve my problem by re installing angular-cli... seriously i don't understand why, maybe a version problem?

Comment: same issue here on prod build while it works with ng `ng serve` (and cache disabled)...

Comment: have you try to reinstall angular cli as i have done? What version do you have? Your styles, are inline styles or the style in the main.css?

Comment: Same issue, I tried css, scss, sass. All of them produce an empty styles file after `ng build --prod --aot`. I have not yet ejected the webpack config, but if nothing can fix it I'll have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but Angular's CLI now includes some CSS optimization options which just now caused my app's global stylesheet to output as `media=print`.

Despite having NO print MQs, this media attr obviously causes no styles to be applied.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ... href="styles.css" media="print">
```

```
"architect": ...
"build": ...
"configurations": {
  "dev": {
    ...
    "optimization": {
      "scripts": true,
      "styles": {
        "minify": true,
        "inlineCritical": false <--- fix
      },
      "fonts": true
    }
```

Comment: The `media="print"` thing is [a hack to make the the stylesheet load asynchronously](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler/).  What you've omitted in your snippet is the `onload="this.media='all'"` handler on the same `link` element, which changes the `media` attribute to `all` after the stylesheet has loaded.  This is an optimisation to stop the downloading and parsing of non-critical CSS from blocking the initial render.  Downside is it requires  `unsafe-inline` or `unsafe-hashes` script-src CSP policy otherwise the onload handler is blocked.

Comment: Hi @daiscog that's a big detail. Can you link me/us to an official source for this?

Comment: Some useful links:

1. https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2021/01/21/angular-cli-11.1/#critical-css-inlining

2. https://dev.to/0xdbe/angular-security-disable-inline-critical-css-2n9g

3. https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-optimization-options