# Using @media print with Angular doesn't work

Tags: angular, printing, media-queries

I'm trying to create a printable page using Angular (5+), however I'm having trouble with the styles.

The content I'm trying to print is inside a component and the style is being sent with a file defined under the stylesUrls, like this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'print-page.html',
    styleUrls: [
        '_print-page.scss'
    ],
})
```

Ant the styles like this:

```
@media print {
    body *:not(#print),
    aside {
        display: none !important;
    }

    #print {
        figure {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I open the print tab the page the figure elements are hidden, but the the aside element, for example, is still showing on the page. It's not being hidden.

I tried to move the styles out of the component and set it direct on the styles file. When I do this, the other elements are hidden, including the div to be printed. No matter what I do, I can't prevent the style to show only the `#print` div.

What should I do?

Comment: Try to added your .ts file to inline .css like this

popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><style>css here...</style> QR Code </head><body  onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using angular cli move your print scss to `.angular-cli.json` file. In this way it will be available and ready when your component loaded.

```
  "prefix": "xyz",
  "styles": [
    "_print-page.scss",
    "style.scss",
```

You can read view reder option for more details

Comment: I already tried this. I mean, I didn't set the scss file under the styles, but imported it direct on the `style.scss` file. It removed the elements, etc.. But it didn't applied any other style to the div with id print.

Comment: `@media` properties are I think page lavel rather component level. try once by directly added in the cli configuration if it works. not sure why its not injecting to the html thought

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69336136/1440240