# Angular 16 @media print in style.css doesn't work

Tags: html, css, angular, media-queries

I have an angular component (ViewTask) with a template which is rendered in  in side app component. App component also has side nav bar. When I print ViewTask component I want to hide/remove everything except what's inside 'print-section' div.

So I am trying to use media query to hide other content on the page. I have added it in style.css

```
@media print {
  body {
    padding: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red !important;
  }
 
}
```

but when I try to print the page, it doesn't have that style. I have tried using @media screen { } and that works fine.

Am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is the same case ["Using @media print with Angular doesn't work"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174061/using-media-print-with-angular-doesnt-work)

Comment: @gsvart I had look at that. In that case, style was working as elements were removed/hidden but the issue I thing was setting display:none which removes dom element. But I will still try to put it in separate style sheet and add it in angular.json.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, got it working.

by default background color is removed in print dialog. To get it working add below lines

```
body{
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact !important;
    print-color-adjust:exact !important;
  }
```

And for other style, just make sure its not overwritten by component level style. In case of multiple '!important', component level style with '!important' will win.