# Update to angular 12 gives CSP unsafe-eval error in chrome extention

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have a working chrome extension which uses angular 11. I just updated it to 12 and now I get

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline
> execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style
> attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes'
> keyword is present.

So, I figured that if it used to work in Angular 11, it should be possible to get it to work in Angular 12.

So, in my manifest I already have:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'
```

I tried adding the `unsafe-hashes` to the angular's index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-oFP6B0o0upf5CwDxtOuL0J68WAdmyZUBtL/g8VBQ9wE='; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'self';">
```

But this doesn't fix that error (even more errors)

It is a public repository, the branch with the update can be found [here](https://github.com/scaljeri/oh-my-mock/tree/feature/82-angular-12)

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Find a way to configure Angular so it doesn't use unsafe-eval.

Answer (score 7):

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67565858/angular-12-css-optimization-inline-event-handler-with-content-security-policy) I found something that fixed the issue

[image]

Then run the production build

```
$> ng build --configuration production
```

and it works :) If there are better solutions please let me know!