# Angular build with optimization cause index file error

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, optimization, build

My company added an Angular app to the existing ASP.NET MVC project last year. The Angular index host webpage is a .cshtml file that contain razor code, eg `@RenderSection("SharedCss", false)` .

It works fine until we upgrade to Angular 12 last week. When build the Angular app with optimization option ( `ng build --optimization` ), the output index.cshtml file is modified erroneously.

### Original index.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/">

    <!-- razor code start-->
      @RenderSection("SharedCss", false)
    <!-- razor code end-->

  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Expected result

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/">

    <!-- razor code start-->
      @RenderSection("SharedCss", false)
    <!-- razor code end-->

    <style>:root{--blue:#007bff;.........</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></noscript>

  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.js" ............ </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Erroneous result

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/">

    <!-- razor code start-->
      </head><body>@RenderSection("SharedCss", false)
    <!-- razor code end-->

    <style>:root{--blue:#007bff;.........</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></noscript>

    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.js" ............ </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `</head><body>` html is erroneously moved to before the razor code (see line between `<!-- razor code start-->` and `<!-- razor code end-->`). It seems during the build optimization process, when Angular cannot parse the unexpected html syntax (eg. razor code) in the head tag, then it would append the `</head>` tag to end the html head element.

---

Note:

1. To eliminate the upgrade factor, I create new empty Angular app, and the issue still exist.
2. this occurs after Angular 12+

I have not be able to find anyone mention this behavior/issue. I would still want to turn the optimization flag on when build for production environment. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found the workaround solution base on this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67565858/angular-12-css-optimization-inline-event-handler-with-content-security-policy)

We apply the same fix by disabling the `inlineCritical` option.

here is an example workspace configuration

```
  "optimization": {
     "scripts": true,
     "styles": {
        "minify": true,
        "inlineCritical": false
     },
     "fonts": true
  }
```